# My test doesn't pass but expectation return correct value (truffle)

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

I have a voting Contract which contains 3 functions , 1 Struct, 1 mapping, 1 modifier and I use Ownable from openzeppelin :

```
struct Voter {
        bool isRegistered;
        bool hasVoted;
        uint votedProposalId;
    }

mapping (address => Voter) public voters;

modifier onlyVoters() {
        require(voters[msg.sender].isRegistered, "You're not a voter");
        _;
    }

    function getVoter(address _addr) external onlyVoters view returns (Voter memory) {
        return voters[_addr];
    }

    function addVoter(address _addr) external onlyOwner {

        voters[_addr].isRegistered = true;
    }
```

When I test the function getVoter in JS, I have the revert's message "You're not a voter" but my test return voter.isRegistered => true so I should be registered and get the voter

JS Test:

```js
contract('Voting', accounts => {
    const owner = accounts[0];
    const firstVoter = accounts[1];
    const secondVoter = accounts[2];

    let votingInstance;

    describe('test getVoter', () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
            votingInstance = await Voting.new({from: owner});
            await votingInstance.addVoter(firstVoter, {from: owner});
        })

        it('should get the address voter', async () => {
            let voters1 = await votingInstance.voters(firstVoter);
            // It return true so I'm registered
            expect(voters1.isRegistered).to.equal(true);
            //Here I've got the message from the modifier "You're not a voter"
            const storeData = await votingInstance.getVoter(firstVoter);
        });
    });

})
```

I don't understand why my test isn't passing, any idea ?

Comment: Probably incorrect await and property read usage, so the test did not wait for the execution result. It should be `expect(await voters1.isRegistered()).to.equal(true);` or somewhat similar.

Comment: This expectation works, its really the getVoter the problem